# Is it possible to disable IPython from the Eclipse/PyDev console?

Tags: eclipse, ipython, pydev

The most recent releases of PyDev IDE for Eclipse come with IPython 'embeded' in its interactive console. I'm just wondering if there is a way to disable this option and let PyDev uses a regular python interactive console without uninstalling IPython? I know that if IPython is not installed PyDev will use a regular python interactive console. But I think there must be a way of doing it without getting rid of IPython.

If somebody knows how to do this, pleas advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no option to do that in the UI.

You can do that in a hackish way by manually opening:

plugins\org.python.pydev\pysrc\pydev_ipython_console.py

in your Eclipse installation and uncommenting the 'raise ImportError()' in the top of the file :)

Now, I'm a bit curious on why you'd prefer the PyDev version instead of the IPython version in this case...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fabio. It worked smoothly. Now, I'm starting to figure out some of PyDev's structure. As for your question, I also was curious why PyDev doesn't allow users to use different python interpreter consoles. IPython is terrific, don't get me wrong. However, sometimes one just wants to have a plain, simple python console (with no extra superpowers) to test snippets of one's code :p

Comment: Works great, don't know why this was downvoted. The exact path was `plugins/org.python.pydev_3.7.0.201408261926/pysrc/pydev_ipython_console.py` on my system, and the file even says to comment the line out if one doesn't want iPython. As for a reason: I'm debugging a program that implements terminal-like functionality, and it doesn't get along well with iPython.